# How to match the words or characters in a text column in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets' say I have these words, and I want to look for all these three keywords in a sentence.

```
keywords_to_track = ["crypto exchange", "loses", "$"] 
# here $ is character because it could appear like "30m$"


0       The $600M Crypto Heist (And How It Impacts ...
1             What Is a Decentralized Crypto Exchange?
2    Crypto Breaches And Fraud Increasing 41% Every...
3            Crypto Exchange Binance Loses $21M in Hack
4    Cryptocurrency hacks and fraud are on track fo...
Name: title, dtype: object
```

If you see, the 3rd index has all these words in a sentence that I need to track. The output I want is,

```
0       False
1       False
2       False
3       True
4       False
Name: title, dtype: bool
```

I tried this but I don't want or operator rather and, I don't think my attempt is correct

```
dataframe.title.str.lower().str.match("crypto exchange|loses|$")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `keywords_to_track` like this:

```
# add \ before $
keywords_to_track = ["crypto exchange", "loses", "\$"]
```

Now use `str.findall`:

```
words = fr"({'|'.join(keywords_to_track)})"

df['match_all'] = df['title'].str.lower() \
                             .str.findall(words) \
                             .apply(lambda x: len(set(x)) == len(keywords_to_track))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                               title  match_all
0     The $600M Crypto Heist (And How It Impacts ...      False
1           What Is a Decentralized Crypto Exchange?      False
2  Crypto Breaches And Fraud Increasing 41% Every...      False
3         Crypto Exchange Binance Loses $21M in Hack       True
4  Cryptocurrency hacks and fraud are on track fo...      False
5                    Crypto exchange Crypto exchange      False
```